# Upgrading to Mobile First 6.3 Server shows No runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

The client has upgraded the worklight server 6.2 to Mobile First 6.3, and deployed the updated war file. Now when we open the console to deploy the adapter, "It shows no runtime can be found"

But the same project works fine in the local development environment, where we installed the mobilefirst studio plugin in eclipse. We are able to build the project and run the app.

Java - 1.7
Eclipse - Juno SR2
MobileFirst studio 6.3

Cannot access the remote server for now, will attach the logs shortly.

Kindly let us know if there are any known issues on upgrading to 6.3(mobile first) from 6.2(worklight)

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the logs? Upload the messages.log and server.xml files of your remote server. When the runtime does not load, this is typically a configuration issue.

Comment: @IdanAdar we are able to fix it. The reason is the client has not built the war file in 6.3, they have updated the old war, when we tried building the war file from the 6.3 and deployed. it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Hi we are able to fix it. The reason is the client has not built the war file in 6.3, they have updated the old war, when we tried building the war file from the 6.3 and deployed. it worked.